# Activity to Fragment communication onlocation changed

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, location

I have implemented location service on my activity ,,,,when i get the location on onlocation changed....i'll b using Geocoder to convert it into a address...now i need to set the value in a fragment within view pager...how to do that..please help..

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    address = Utility.getAddress(RegistrationPersonaliseActivity.this, location);

    Log.e("tag", "Lat-->" + latitude + "long-->" + longitude + "Address-->" + address);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    address = Utility.getAddress(RegistrationPersonaliseActivity.this, location);

    Prefs.setLoc(address);
}


    final Handler ha=new Handler();
    ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //call function
            place.setText(Prefs.getLoc());
            ha.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }, 10000);
```